# Which RegExp template should I use for [some|text]?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `[some|text]`. Which RegExp template should I use?
I have already tried `/\[.|.\]/gi` but it doesn't work.
I need to do from `[https://google.com|Google]` this: `<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>`
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems with your pattern:

- You're matching just a single character with `.`, instead of a series of characters
- `|` has special meaning, so you have to escape it as you did `[` and `]` (you don't actually have to escape `]`)
- If you want to capture the text either side of `|`, you need capture groups

So adding the `*`s and the escape, and using `String#replace` with `$1` for the first capture group and `$2` for the second:

```js
var str = "[https://google.com|Google]";
var rex = /\[(.*)\|(.*)\]/gi;
var result = str.replace(rex, '<a href="$1">$2</a>');

console.log(result);
```